# A system of quadratic Diophantine equations with four variables

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Is the following system has any positive integer solution $(x,y,u,v)$?
$$\begin{cases} x^2+y^2=u^2\\ x^2-y^2=v^2 \end{cases}$$
I can prove that any pair of these integers can be relatively prime, but I couldn't find any solution. Any hint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are no (nontrivial) solutions. Note that in any solution, the numbers $v^2,x^2,u^2$ would be in arithmetic progression with common difference $y^2$. One can parametrize all three-term arithmetic progressions of squares (see for example [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/3squarearithprog.pdf)) and characterize which common differences can occur. From the paper, having a square as a common difference would correspond to nontorsion rational points on the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-x$, which don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

From solutions of the Pythagorean equation we have $x = 2ab, y = a^2 - b^2$, so we must have $$(a^2 - b^2 - 2ab)(a^2 - b^2 + 2ab) = v^2$$ we have $(a^2 - b^2 - 2ab, a^2 - b^2 + 2ab) = 1$, so $$a^2 - b^2 - 2ab = (a - b)^2 - 2b^2 = x^2$$ $$a^2 - b^2 + 2ab = (a + b)^2 - 2b^2 = y^2$$ your equation has solution if and only if the Bell equations, $x^2 - 2b^2 = m^2$, $y^2 + 2b^2 = n^2$ have solutions for $(m, n)$ such that $2|m+n$, you can easily find all solutions of this equations and I think you can find some solutions this way.

Answer (score 0):

A rearrangement of variables in the "given" shows two Pythagorean triples where the odd leg of one triple matches the hypotenuse of another.
\begin{equation}
 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x^2+y^2=u^2\\
 x^2-y^2=v^2\implies x^2=y^2+v^2
\end{equation}
We can find matching x and matching y separatately such as

\begin{equation} 
x_1:x_2 \quad (17,144,145)\land(17,15,8)\quad\text{or}\quad\\ 
y_1:y_2 \quad (17,144,145)\land (108,144,180)\land (5183,144,5185)
\end{equation}

but if two numbers of one triple match two numbers of another triple, then both the third number of both triple must also be identical.
If we permit y to be different, the example of $(x_1:x_2)$ works except that
$GCD(15,145)=5\land GCD(8,144)=8$.
We  can find such as

$$(35,12,37)\land (37,684,685)$$
but here, as in all triples, the y-term is a multiple of $4$ so it is not possible for all of the terms to be mutually prime.
If you want to explore this further, the following formula permits you to find all triples that exist for a given odd number as side-C. By testing we can find the m-values in range that yield an integer k. Then we use Euclid's formula where $ \quad A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2\quad$

\begin{equation}
C=m^2+k^2\implies k=\sqrt{C-m^2}\qquad\text{for}\qquad \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{2C-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \lfloor\sqrt{C-1}\rfloor
\end{equation}

The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$C=65\implies \bigg\lfloor\frac{ 1+\sqrt{130-1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=6 \le m \le \lfloor\sqrt{65-1}\rfloor=8\quad\land \quad m\in\{7,8\}\Rightarrow k\in\{4,1\}\\$$
$$F(7,4)=(33,56,65)\qquad \qquad F(8,1)=(63,16,65) $$

Just remember that side-B is always a multiple of $4$ so they can never be mutually prime.